# Where do I go to find the current contents of the async queue?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

C# provides Tasks and async. I put a task on the queue from an async method by saying:

```
private async Task DoThing() {
    var results = await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        // do some things
    }
// do other async things
}
```

I put a break-point inside the Task.Run, but it's never called. I understand that it normally would be called; but I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere else.

This led me to wonder, though: where can I find out the current contents of the queue that the task factory is using to decide what task to work on next? I've made several Google queries on the subject but I can't seem to find anything. Is it possible to inspect the work queue itself to see what's there?

Comment: Can you post a [short but complete program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: The issue I was having in code wasn't related me wanting to see what tasks are in queue, so I didn't list it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see currently executing and scheduled tasks from the [Tasks Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998369.aspx) in Visual Studio when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The thread pool does not expose any means of seeing the items that have been queued into it.